# Sql Server - For Xml Auto - C# Data Set

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml

```
var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, sqlConnection);
sqlConnection.Open();
XmlReader xmlReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteXmlReader();
var dataSet = new DataSet();
dataSet.ReadXml(xmlReader, XmlReadMode.Auto);
```

> System.Xml.XmlException: hexadecimal value 0x1C, is an invalid character

1.Sql Procedure return XML Data.
2.Load XML Data to DataSet Object and return to another method.
3.dataSet.ReadXml - I am getting error. Yes my procedure return some invalid char [&#x1].

Question: How can i resolve this issue? Best place to fix - Sql Procedure or in my C# method?

Comment: How is the SP generating your XML? Might help to show an example of your XML and the SQL code... `.ReadXml` should work, as long as the XML is convenient for this method. You cannot read *any XML* like this..

Comment: Procedure joins the table based on business requirements. End of the select statement in the procedure like  - FOR XML AUTO, ROOT('Report'). So in my XmlReader, i need to remove invalid char before dataset read xml from XmlReader

Comment: Please use the edit option to add a (reduced) example of your XML (including the *bad* character). Is there a *schema* included?